# How to set hyperlink in rdlc for both localhost and server?

Tags: reporting, rdlc, report

I am using rdlc reporting to display report, in rdlc report I was set hyperlink for another report like:

```
    ="http://localhost:8080/ReportForms/RECRptAdvertisement.aspx?
    reqid="&Fields!RequirementID.Value
```

From above URL my hyperlink working fine in localhost but if I change it to this:

```
    ="~/RECRptAdvertisement.aspx?reqid="&Fields!RequirementID.Value
```

It is not working. So how do I set my hyperlink url to be workable in localhost as well as in server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the Server Url to the report as a Parameter, then your expression for the textbox should reference that local report parameter.

Add a new Parameter to your report and set it to `=Parameters!ReportParameterUrl.Value`

When Loading the ReportViewer, set the correct url:

```
        baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + @"://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + '/';
        ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("ReportParameterUrl", baseUrl);
        this.rvMyReport.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });
```

Finally, your text box expressions should be

```
=Parameters!ReportParameterUrl.Value + "RECRptAdvertisement.aspx?reqid="&Fields!RequirementID.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass a value to the URL manually to see if it behaves the sameway on localhost URL and named instance? what about trying via IP as well?

something like...

```
="~/RECRptAdvertisement.aspx?reqid=20001298"
```